# Socket.io write file to user disk

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node.js web app that has a button. When this button is pressed, it gathers data and sends the data to a socket.io function. Here is the client code:

```
$("body").on('click', ".download", function() {
             
    var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  
    socket.emit('download_data', data);
}
```

On the sever side I have a socket.io function that gets the data:

```
socket.on('download_data', function(data){
    //create csv and download
});
```

I want the socket function to create a CSV file with the generated data and write the file to the users disk. Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server, generate the content of the CSV file:

```js
csv = '';
data.forEach(row => { // Assuming an array of arrays.
  csv += row.join(';') + '\n';
});
```

Return the content to the client:

```js
socket.emit('csv_content', csv);
```

On the client, ask the user to download or open. I am using the file-saver package here.

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
saveAs(blob, "data.csv");
```

Not sure why you are using socket.io for this, as you can do the same with a HTTP POST operation.

Comment: Life saver, thank you. I inherited a project two days ago and this is a required feature needed today so I just needed a valid answer. Enjoy the rep!